# SimplePie document parse error

Tags: laravel, simplepie

I am trying to implement Simplepie in my laravel application to parse feeds, but when I do, I get this error:

> This XML document is invalid, likely due to invalid characters. XML
>   error: Not well-formed (invalid token) at line 1, column 1

The feed is this one: `https://www-304.ibm.com/connections/blogs/roller-ui/rendering/feed/PSIRT/entries/atom?search=cn4093&t=entry&f=all&lang=en_us` and it works great in the demo app, but fails locally.

Here what I am doing:

```
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url("https://www-304.ibm.com/connections/blogs/roller-ui/rendering/feed/PSIRT/entries/atom?search=cn4093&t=entry&f=all&lang=en_us");
$feed->enable_cache(true);
$feed->set_cache_location(storage_path().'/cache');
$feed->set_cache_duration(60*60*12);
$feed->set_output_encoding('utf-8');
$feed->force_feed(true)
$feed->init();
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be because of the SSL (https) connection you are trying to load. Please read this: https://github.com/simplepie/simplepie/issues/236

It includes the fix to download the RSS using cURL and include it's result into the SimplePie class to parse.

UPDATE:
Read the comment by manishbhatias commented on 20 Jul 2011, on: https://github.com/simplepie/simplepie/issues/82

sharing the same issue you have. He believes it had something to do with the method SimplePie uses to urlencode parameters in the URL. You could create a proxy PHP script and see if that solves the issue for you.

`<?php 
    echo file_get_contents('https://www-304.ibm.com/connections/blogs/roller-ui/rendering/feed/PSIRT/entries/atom?search=cn4093&t=entry&f=all&lang=en_us'); 
?>`

Comment: I had already added the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` but I still get the same error if I specify `$feed->force_feed(true)`, if I don't the feed cannot be located.

Comment: And the issue is only when using the ibm feed?

Comment: It could also have something to do with the PHP version you are running. (Can you look this up?)

Comment: I am actually using `PHP 5.5.23-1+deb.sury.org~precise+2 (cli) (built: Mar 24 2015 11:00:01)`

Comment: Have you checked my original answer? I added an update based on something I found on github.